# How can i rewrite or convert this C++ code to Haskell code

Tags: oop, haskell

The c++ code which i wanted to rewrite or convert is:

```
class numberClass
{
    private:
    int value;
    public:
    int read()
    {
        return value;
    }
    void load(int x)
    {
        value = x;
    }
    void increment()
    {
        value= value +1;
    }
};

int main()
{
    numberClass num;
    num.load(5);
    int x=num.read();
    cout<<x<<endl;
    num.increment();
    x=num.read();
    cout<<x;
}
```

I do not know how to make any entity(like variable in C++) that can hold value throughout the program in haskell.

Please help.
 Thanks

Comment: Is this homework?  As a first step, try refactoring the C++ code to eliminate variables.

Comment: If that is homework, somebody should slap the teacher with a wet salmon. A whole month long.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, assuming that it's the wrapping, not the mutability, you can easily have a type that only allows constructing constant values and incrementation:

```
module Incr (Incr, incr, fromIncr, toIncr) where

newtype Incr a = Incr a deriving (Read, Show)

fromIncr :: Incr a -> a
fromIncr (Incr x) = x

incr :: (Enum a) => Incr a -> Incr a
incr (Incr x) = Incr (succ x)

toIncr :: a -> Incr a
toIncr = Incr
```

As Daniel pointed out, mutability is out of the question, but another purpose of your class is encapsulation, which this module provides just like the C++ class.  Of course to a Haskell programmer, this module might not seem very useful, but perhaps you have use cases in mind, where you want to statically prevent library users from using regular addition or multiplication.

Answer (score 10):

Basically, you can't. Values are immutable, and Haskell has no variables in the sense of boxes where you store values, like C++ and similar. You *can* do something similar using `IORef`s (which are boxes you can store values in), but it's almost always a wrong design to use them.

Haskell is a *very* different programming language, it's not a good idea to try to translate code from a language like C, C++, Java or so to Haskell. One has to view the tasks from different angles and approach it in a different way.

That being said:

```
module Main (main) where

import Data.IORef

main :: IO ()
main = do
    num <- newIORef 5 :: IO (IORef Int)
    x <- readIORef num
    print x
    modifyIORef num (+1)
    x <- readIORef num
    print x
```

Answer (score 2):

A direct translation of your code to haskell is rather stupid but of course possible (as shown in Daniel's answer).
Usually when you are working with state in haskell you might be able to work with the `State Monad`. As long as you are executing inside the State Monad you can query and update your state. If you want to be able to do some IO in addition (as in your example), you need to stack your State Monad on top of IO.
Using this approach your code might look like this:

```
import Control.Monad.State
import Prelude hiding(read)

increment = modify (+1)
load = put
read = get

normal :: StateT Int IO ()
normal = do
    load 5
    x <- read
    lift (print x)
    increment
    x <- read
    lift (print x)

main = evalStateT normal 0
```

But here you don't have an explicit type for your numberClass. If you want this there is a nice library on hackage that you could use: [data-lenses](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-lens-2.0.2).
Using lenses the code might be a little closer to your C++ version:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
import Control.Monad.State(StateT,evalStateT,lift)
import Prelude hiding(read)
import Data.Lens.Lazy((~=),access,(%=))
import Data.Lens.Template(makeLenses)

data Number = Number {
  _value :: Int
} deriving (Show)
$( makeLenses [''Number] )

increment = value %= succ
load x = value ~= x
read = access value

withLens :: StateT Number IO ()
withLens = do
    load 5
    x <- read
    lift $ print x
    increment
    x <- read
    lift $ print x

main = evalStateT withLens (Number 0)
```

Still not exactly your code...but well, it's haskell and not yet another OO-language.